# USER_PRESENT Intent for GO Locker

Tags: android, android-intent

My app listens for the USER_PRESENT intent. However, custom lock-screen-replacements, such as WidgetLocker and GO Locker don't/can't send this protected broadcast.

WidgetLocker provides a workaround to this by broadcasting its own custom intents (e.g. `com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.UNLOCKED`, [see here](http://teslacoilsw.com/widgetlocker/#developers)). Does GO Locker provide similar intents? I wasn't able to find any information on this.

Comment: I have emailed the developer of GO Locker, but haven't heard back from them.

Comment: I have also emailed the developer, and although I heard back from them, they didn't seem to be aware of what an Android intent *IS*. I thought it was a fairly central part of the Android APIs.... In any event, after explaining it to them, I then didn't hear back.

Comment: Wow, that's...interesting, considering the success of their app! Thanks for letting me know! I guess we're out of luck, then, unless we write the code for them ourselves ;-)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you don't mind that I'm posting this so late in this thread, but I needed to do exactly the same and found the Intent actions which they are using:

- com.jiubang.goscreenlock.unlock
- com.jiubang.goscreenlock.appunlock
- com.jiubang.goscreenlock.close

Please note that I only managed to get the first one to work. I never saw the other two fired by GO Locker, but the second one looks like it could be used in some cases. Last one seems a bit ominous/unclear, so use it at your own risk.

If anyone is interested how I found these then it was by decompiling the GO Locker APK with apktool and grepping for package name patterns in the smali files (thank you for not being able to obfuscate string literals!).

Comment: AWESOME, thank you SO much! This has been bugging me for months! I've extracted tons of different Intents from the GO Locker APK, but never managed to find the right one. This is a life-saver! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it was of help. I went through quite a few strings in grep output, up to the point of getting a headache, but these three stood out and worked to my content (well one of them)!

Comment: I sent several mails to them but never got any answer. Thank you so much for finding out the answer yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of GO Locker are you using? Send me the .apk file and I may help you, cause I have had a similar problem before.`wenqs27@gmail.com`

I'm using Go Locker 1.35.1 and the intent should be`com.gau.go.launcherex_action_send_togolock`
which is recieved by `com.jiubang.goscreenlock.service.KeyguardReciever`

Hope this will help you~

Comment: Hi Wings, thanks for your reply! That's a great idea to simply look at the source-code to find out the intents. But I thought apps could define some intents as "private" to their own app (i.e. not a system-wide broadcast that my app could receive, too)? What I'm looking for is the *unlock*-intent, meaning when the user has used Go-Locker to return to the Go-Launcher-Homescreen.